# Using FMDB + SQLCipher with Rubymotion?

Tags: ios6, fmdb, rubymotion, sqlcipher, cocoapods

I am using FMDB for handling a sqlite db in my application built using rubymotion.

I want to encryt the database with SQLCipher and I am facing issues when I try using SQLCipher methods such as **sqlite3_key** ?

Has anyone tried out the same ?

**************adding :

When I try to encrypt the database using the sqlite3_key method offered by SQLCipher api , it throws and exception telling the method is not defined.

---

Comment: Can you be more specific on the issues you face? Error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by adding `SQLCipher` pod then using the `FMDB` `FMDatabase.setKey` method and without having to do write any C.

In the `Rakefile`

```
app.pods do
  pod 'FMDB'
  pod 'SQLCipher'
end
```

Then in your `Database.rb`

```
class Database
  def self.connection
    unless @connection
      @connection = FMDatabase.databaseWithPath(db_path)
      @connection.traceExecution = true if $debug
      @connection.open
      @connection.setKey 'MySecretKey'
    end
  end
end
```

Now you should be able to query the db with

```
Database.connection.executeSelect 'SELECT * from some_table'
```

Comment: yep I did that already after going through the many hits and trials !